# Is there any way to get all the data from routes in angular4 like ionic NavParams?

Tags: angular

this one code is from the ionic and I wanted to use the same process in angular CLI? is it possible?

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of items$ | async"
    detail-push navPush="EditPage" [navParams]="{item:item}">
</ion-item>
```

I know it will not work like this but is there a way to use the params like this in angular?

```
<a routerLink="/editPage" [navParams]="{{ item.item }}">{{item.title}}</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no **navParams** with angular, but you can use **`routerLink`** instead

```
<a [routerLink]="['/editPage', item.item]">{{item.title}}</a>
```

Comment: yeah i know this one I'm trying to get the whole observable data like in ionic so i don't have to query again? or is there any other way ?

Comment: what do you mean by dont have to query again, above also you do not need to

Comment: @sageetharan I'm sorry ? is it possible to pass all the data from the array ? to params ? like  _ngFor="let item of items$ | async"_  to  _item.item_ ? but it's says that it's undefined ?

Comment: no you cannot pass all the data in a url, you need @input event emitter

Comment: i see I I thought it's possible like in ionic so i'll mark it as an answer :) thanks